# How can I customize the http status code in Spring-Security for a special case authentication failure?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm writing a RESTful service, with no user interface, so there's no error page. When I get an expired token, I want to set a specific error code and message, so the caller knows it needs to log in again. (I'm not worried about giving hackers extra information because I only see this case when the token has the correct digital signature.) I've tried three different approaches.

1. Throw a CredentialsExpiredException, which extends AuthenticationException. I've installed an `AuthenticationEntryPoint` to process the Exception, but Spring Security sends it a different exception. So there's no way to distinguish between my custom failure and a standard authentication rejection.
2. Throw a custom exception, annotated with `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED)`.
   This should generate an error code of 417, but I get a 403-Forbidden. I also tried adding a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`, but that has no effect.
3. I set a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` into the `SecurityContext`, but with an empty credentials list. This generates a response with the same 403 Http status as any other failure mode. There's no way to specify a different status code or message.

I install my `AuthenticationEntryPoint` into my WebSecurityConfig like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("HardcodedFileSeparator")
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  log.trace("Configuring WebSecurityConfig");

  /* The /view/** path requires no authentication. The others start with /admin, and require the ADMIN role. */
  http
      .csrf()
        .disable()
      .cors()
        .disable()
      .formLogin()
        .disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**")
          .hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/view/**")
          .permitAll()
      .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
      .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
      .and()
      .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
      .and()
        .addFilterBefore(requestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
  ;
}
```

The requestFilter, which I install in the last line above, is where I throw the exception that I thought would get sent to the `AuthenticationEntryPoint`.

I don't know why the `@ResponseStatus` annotation doesn't work. And I don't know how to set a specific error code in Spring Security.

I've created a minimal reproducible test case, which you can try out at https://github.com/SwingGuy1024/SecurityQuestion
The README.md file explains how to use it and documents the endpoints it implements. It uses Java 12, but the code will compile under Java 8.

(I know that authentication failures typically shouldn't return much information, to avoid giving hackers any useful information, but I just want to tell the user that their JWT token has expired and they need to log back in. The test case above doesn't use JWT, as it's not necessary to reproduce the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

I never found a way to change the HttpStatus code, but I did find a way to notify the caller that the token has expired. When I detect an expire token, I add a header to the response that specified an expired token. It's not quite what I wanted, but it does the trick.

At one point, I was able to use this header to change the response code in my AuthenticationEntryPoint class. But I just tried it again and it didn't work. I don't know what I changed to break this, but it doesn't matter.